# Deep Merge метод не работает (руби)

Tags: алгоритм, ruby, хеширование, информатика

Доброе время суток.

В данный момент времени пытаюсь написать свою реализацию DSL (Domain Specific Language). Для этого мне нужно реализовать несколько сред(в дальнейшем env), а так же наследование одной среды от другой. Env у меня реализованы таким образом что являются хэшами с вложенными хешами.

Суть проблемы в том, что метод deep_merge, который я позаимствовал из configus гема не работает(или работает не так, как нужно), ниже приведу примеры и код.

Здесь сама модель DSL:

```rb
require "./configus"
require "pry"

#Binding.pry

config = Configus.config :staging, :production do
  production do
    key1 "value1"
    key2 "value2"
    group1 do
      key3 "value3"
      key4 "value4"
    end
  end

  staging do
    key2 "new value2"
    group1 do
      key4 "new value4"
    end
  end
end
```

Configus.config = self.config с параметрами environment и parent, а так же &block
Дальше я создаю хэши

```rb
{:production => {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", :group1 => {key3: "value3", key4: "value4"}}}
{:staging => {key2: "new value2", :group1 => {key4: "new value4"}}}
```

Для вывода значений использую такую команду:

```rb
p config.key_name 
#Например:
p config.key1
```

Без использования наследования всё нормально выводится, т.е выводится значения ключа по запросу. Но при использовании наследование, оно не срабатывает:
Как должно быть:

```rb
p config.key1        #=> ["value1"] #Т.к берется значения из production(т.к в env staging нету key1)
p config.key2        #=> ["new value2"] #Тут переписывается ключ key2 из production на ключ key2 из staging
p config.group1.key3 #=> ["value3"]
p config.group1.key4 #=> ["new value4"]
```

Как происходит ПРИ наследовании:

```rb
p config.key1        #=> ["value1"] # Тут всё в порядке, в env staging отсутствует key1
p config.key2        #=> ["value2"] # А вот тут уже совсем не всё в порядке, т.к должно быть ["new value2"], т.е значение ключа из env staging
p config.key3        #=> ["value3"] # Тут всё в порядке
p config.key4        #=> ["value4"] # Та же самая проблема
```

Привожу ниже саму реализацию DSL:

```rb
class Configus
  class InHash
    attr_reader :inner_hash

    def initialize
      @inner_hash = {}
    end

    def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
      if block_given?
        context = InHash.new
        context.instance_eval &block
        @inner_hash[name] = context
      elsif args.empty?
        @inner_hash[name]
      else
        @inner_hash[name] = args
      end
    end

    def deep_merge(target, source)
      source.each_pair do |k, v|
        tv = target[k]
        target[k] = tv.is_a?(Hash) && v.is_a?(Hash) ? deep_merge(tv, v) : v
      end
      target
    end
  end

  def self.config(environment, parent = nil, &block)
    in_hash = InHash.new
    in_hash.instance_eval &block
    keys = in_hash.inner_hash.keys
    index = keys.find_index(environment)
    if parent && environment
      parent_hash = in_hash.inner_hash[parent]
      adopted_hash = in_hash.inner_hash[environment]
      merged_hash = InHash.deep_merge(parent_hash, adopted_hash)
    elsif environment == keys[index]
      in_hash.inner_hash[environment]
    end
  end
end
```

А так же хэши, что выводятся при p config в различных ситуациях:
При наследовании env'ов(т.е production И staging):

```rb
p config 

#<Configus::InHash:0x000055aace975990 @inner_hash={:key1=>["value1"], :key2=>["value2"], :group1=>#<Configus::InHash:0x000055aace975288 @inner_hash={:key3=>["value3"], :key4=>["value4"]}>, :[]=>[#<Configus::InHash:0x000055aace983a90 @inner_hash={:deep_merge=>[[...], nil]}>], :[]==>[#<Configus::InHash:0x000055aace983a90 @inner_hash={:deep_merge=>[[#<Configus::InHash:0x000055aace983a90 ...>], nil]}>, [[#<Configus::InHash:0x000055aace983a90 @inner_hash={:deep_merge=>[...]}>], nil]]}>
```

Без наследования env'ов(т.е production ИЛИ staging):

```rb
p config

#<Configus::InHash:0x00005625a9771760 @inner_hash={:key1=>["value1"], :key2=>["value2"], :group1=>#<Configus::InHash:0x00005625a9771288 @inner_hash={:key3=>["value3"], :key4=>["value4"]}>}>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за кривую реализацию ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯